# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have been trying to use dynamic scaffolding in groovy on grails to see the list of the Tasks. My domain class is as follows

```
package projecttracker

import java.util.Date;

class Task 
{
    String name
    String description
    Date dueDate

    String toString() {
        "${name}"
    }

    static belongsTo = [enduser: EndUser ,project: Project]

    static constraints = {

        name()
        description()
        dueDate() 
    }
}
```

My controller class is as follows:

```
package projecttracker

class TaskController {
    def scaffold =true 

    def index() {
        redirect(action:list)
    }
}
```

But, whenever I call the index method of the Task controller,  the following error occurs:

```
URI :     /ProjectTracker/task/index
Class:    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
Message:  No such property: list for class: projecttracker.TaskController Possible solutions: edit, flash, class
Around line 7 of grails-app\controllers\projecttracker\TaskController.groovy
4:  def scaffold =true 
5:
6:    def index() {
7:      redirect(action:list)
8:  }
9:}
```

Can someone tell me, how to define the list method here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a string for the method name, and the scaffold variable must be static, i.e.

static scaffold = true

def index() {
      redirect(action:'list')
}

Comment: If i make the function name a string, then it causes "HTTP status 404" error.

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using? If you are using Grails 3, there is no longer support for scaffolding - sadly enough

Comment: If you are using version 2.3.0 - 2.5.0 there is no list method in the scaffolded code, as the index method acts as the old list method.
In grails < 2.3.0, the reply above should work

Comment: Thanks jacob. Finally I have figured out the difference between the versions using cmd command :
grails generate-all projecttracker.EndUser